# Uib-paginator - one-time binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-translate

**Introduction**

Now I'm using uib-paginator in my Angular 1.6 app. I want to be able to change some bindings after the application has started. E.g. in this case I want to change the language at any time.

It looks like some uib-paginator directive bindings use one-time binding. So I can only affect them once.

**Usage**

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="3"
    ng-model="currentPage"
    class="Pagination"
    boundary-links="true"
    num-pages="numPages"
    items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    first-text="{{'LABEL_FIRST' | translate}}"
    next-text="{{'LABEL_NEXT' | translate}}"
    previous-text="{{'LABEL_PREV' | translate}}"
    last-text="{{'LABEL_LAST'}} | translate"></ul>
```

- These bindings use one-time binding:

  - first-text
  - next-text
  - previous-text
  - last-text

When I change the language, the values of LABEL_* variables will change. But obviously it doesn't affect the paginator.

**Thoughts**

I could probably write jQuery code to refresh that particular element when any of these LABEL_* variables changes. But I want to keep jQuery away from this application as much as I can.

If you have any idea of how I can solve this problem (without jQuery..:) then please share it.

Comment: Could you show or describe the method that translate the labels? I think that you probably have to use a filter to do it...

Comment: I forgot to add the translation filter in the example above. But it doesn't matter. It still doesn't work.

`first-text="{{'LABEL_FIRST' | translate}}"
next-text="{{'LABEL_NEXT' | translate}}"
previous-text="{{'LABEL_PREV' | translate}}"
last-text="{{'LABEL_LAST' | translate}}"`
And the translation works everywhere on that page, except in this paginator directive.

Comment: Are you using `angulari18n` or is a custom translate lib?

Comment: I'm using angular-translate *https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate*

Comment: If you see the [uib-pagination code(line 131)](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/pagination.js) you can check that labels only has one way data binding... I think that could be too hard to change the labels on the fly. It has to be done in a hackish way....

Comment: I've made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/Ln42Lh7j/29/) with your problem... use it for your question if you want. I hope someone find a solution :)

Comment: Thank you Bear :)

I finally got the solution and I will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone who has the same problem:

1.
 This is the uib-paginator template:
*https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/pagination/pagination.html*

Copy it to a .html file.

2.
Modify all

```
{{::getText('x')}} to {{getText('x')}}
```

Or replace it with your own translation (like I did)

```
{{::getText('first')}} to {{'LABEL_FIRST'|translate}}
```

3.
Use the attribute *template-url* in the uib-pagination and reference to the new template.

The new example of my code above will look like this:

```
<ul uib-pagination total-items="3"
ng-model="currentPage"
class="Pagination"
boundary-links="true"
num-pages="numPages"
items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
template-url="../templates/myNewPaginatorTemplate.html"></ul>
```

Voilà.